# Is the Vector of three pairwise Gaussian itself Gaussian?

Tags: probability

If $(X,Y)$, $(X,Z)$, and $(Y,Z)$ are all Gaussian, does it follow that $(X,Y,Z)$ is also Gaussian? I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a counterexample. Start with the usual iid gaussian density in 3 space. Set this density to $0$ on the [octants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octant_(solid_geometry)) $(+,+,+),(-,+,-),(+,-,-),(-,-,+)$, and double the density on the remaining octants. The resulting 3-dimensional density isn't gaussian, e.g., it isn't spherically symmetric, though the bivariate marginals are gaussian.